# Typescript ReturnType with nested functions

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to use `ReturnType` to generate a type that depends on the return types of functions living on an object.

Here is the object:

```
const foo = {
  bar: (): number => 1,
  quux: (): string => 'a',
};
```

The desired resulting type is:

```
type FooLeaves = {
  bar: number;
  quux: string;
};
```

Is it possible to apply a `ResultType` to the values of the object in order to pull the return types out of the nested functions?

I guess I could invoke each value and take the type of that, but it seems hacky

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's pretty straightforward using [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types):

```
type FooLeaves = { [K in keyof typeof foo]: ReturnType<typeof foo[K]> };
```

This is equivalent to

```
type FooLeaves = {
  bar: number;
  quux: string;
};
```

If you'd like a more generic solution, you might use [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#conditional-types) to create something like this:

```
type ResultsOf<T> = { [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends (...args: any) => infer R ? R : T[K] }
```

This will also handle the cases where you mix functions and regular values, for example:

```
const foo = {
  bar: (): number => 1,
  quux: 'a',
};

type FooLeaves = ResultsOf<typeof foo>; // { bar: number, quux: string }
```